# How to read zip submitted by --pyfiles from PySpark application

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, path, operating-system

I have the following folder structure. I zipped the the `source` folder and run `spark-submit` with the `source.zip` as `--py-files`. My problem is, how do I read the `config.hcl` file from the PySpark application? I tried `SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()+'/source/config.hcl'` but that didn't work. The error says no such file or directoy. Many thanks for your help. I'm trying to read `config.hcl` from `app.py`. How do I refer it in a zip? Or how do I unzip it first?

```
source
  | config.hcl
app.py.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main reasons you weren't able to read the `config.hcl` file:

1. When uploading zip file and submit via `--py-files`, the package remains inside zip file without extraction (for example `/private/var/folders/81/c3fgx2qx6nq3lh2v983cdcd80000gn/T/spark-043999a0-c7fb-409c-a95d-4b8a902e55f0/userFiles-c3301b1a-b47e-4411-a2e9-ef0d8c2dc347/a.zip`)
2. Because if (1), the way you read `config.hcl` is a bit different, you'd need to read by [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) instead

I created a test file `a.zip` with the following structure

```
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── a.txt
```

```py
# __init__.py
from .a import *

# a.py
from os import path
from zipfile import ZipFile

def test():
    zip = ZipFile(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
    with zip.open('a/a.txt') as f:
        print(f.readlines())

# a.txt
'Hello World'
```

```py
# spark-submit --py-files a.zip ...
import a
a.test()
# 'Hello World'
```